# 404 error with POST and OkHttp3

Tags: android, okhttp

I'm having an issue posting data to the Challonge API with OkHttp3 on Android... This is the jist of my code:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = new HttpUrl.Builder();
urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse("https://api.challonge.com/v1/tournaments/"+EVENT_ID+".json")
    .newBuilder();

RequestBody postBody = new FormBody.Builder()
    .add("_method", "post")
    .add("api_key", API_KEY)
    .add("participant[name]", name.getText().toString())
    .add("participant[misc]", forum_id.getText().toString())
    .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url(urlBuilder.build().toString())
    .post(postBody)
    .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

No matter what I do, the resulting reponse is a 404 page.

If I do a GET response to the same URL, I get a proper response. However, the moment I add `.post(postBody)` to the request, its immediately 404s.

The documentation for the Challonge API is here:
http://api.challonge.com/v1/documents/participants/create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you're just using the wrong URL. The URL you've got there, `"https://api.challonge.com/v1/tournaments/"+EVENT_ID+".json"`, is the URL for retrieving a single tournament, as seen [here](http://api.challonge.com/v1/documents/tournaments/show). This link was meant to receive GET requests.

According to the link you provided, you should alter your code to POST to `https://api.challonge.com/v1/tournaments/"+EVENT_ID+"/participants.json`

Comment: Oh jeez... I'm an idiot. Had been programming for 20 hours straight and I guess I lost it a bit.